# Inequality proof involving multinomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, factorial, multinomial-coefficients

How may I proceed to prove/disprove following inequality?

$$\frac{n^n}{p_1^{p_1}\cdot p_2^{p_2}\cdots p_k^{p_k}}>\frac{n!}{p_1! p_2!\cdots p_k!}
$$
where
$\sum_{i=1}^k p_i=n$

It seems, using Stirling approximation I need to show that $\sqrt{\frac{p_1
+p_2+...+p_k}{p_1
.p_2...p_k}(2\pi)^{1-k}}$ is less than one for all $n$ and $p_i$.

Comment: I think you're almost get to the answer, because $\sqrt{\frac{p_1
+p_2+...+p_k}{p_1
.p_2...p_k}(2\pi)^{1-k}} < 1$ for $ p_i \in \mathbb{Z}^+$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Shorter proof** :

The inequality is :

$$(p_1+p_2+\ldots+p_k)^{n} > \binom{n}{p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_k} p_1^{p_1} \cdot p_2^{p_2} \cdot \ldots \cdot p_k^{p_k}$$

which is true because the RHS term appears in the multinomial expansion of $(p_1+p_2+\ldots+p_k)^{n}$

**Longer proof** (basically equivalent with the shorter) :

Let $f(x)=\frac{x^x}{x!}$ with $x \in \mathbb{N}$ .

We need to prove that $$f(p_1)f(p_2)\ldots f(p_k) < f(n)$$

So it suffices to prove it for two numbers :

$$f(x)f(y) < f(x+y)$$ and then we can repeatedly apply this to get the general case :

$$f(p_1)f(p_2)\ldots f(p_k) < f(p_1+p_2)f(p_3)\ldots f(p_k) < \ldots <f(p_1+p_2+\ldots +p_k)=f(n)$$

All we need to prove is thus :

$$\frac{x^x y^y}{x! y!} < \frac{(x+y)^{x+y}}{(x+y)!}$$

$$\binom{x+y}{y}x^xy^y <(x+y)^{x+y}$$ which is true because $\binom{x+y}{y}x^xy^y $ is one of the terms in the binomial expansion of $(x+y)^{x+y}$.

Comment: Shorter, the more beautiful one.

Answer (score 2):

Taking logarithms and reshuffling terms turns your inequality into the equivalent

$$\ln(n^n/n!) ~>~ \sum_{i=1}^k \ln(p_i^{p_i}/p_i!)$$
where $\sum_{i=1}^k p_i=n$ and $k\ge2$.

Hence it will be sufficient to show that $f(x)=\ln(x^x/x!)$ is super-linear; that is, that $f$ satisfies $f(a+b)>f(a)+f(b)$.

Comment: But $x!$ is defined only at the natural numbers and so also your function $f$ . Maybe you can change it with $\lfloor x \rfloor !$ or $\Gamma(x+1)$....

Comment: 1.What does "concavity on the integers" means when $f$ is defined only at integers . 2.If you can apply Jensen then you'll get : $$f(p_1)+\ldots+f(p_n) \leq n f \left(\frac{p_1+p_2+\ldots+p_n}{n} \right)=nf(1)=n$$ which is definitely wrong .